# I'm having trouble creating objects and using their class functions using vectors instead of arrays...What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, vector, sdl

I'm new to using vectors...I just started studying them today.  I'm trying to create a vector for my enemy class so I can dynamically create them, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the class functions...

Here is the class...

```
class Enemy
{
    private:
        SDL_Surface *enemy;
    public:
        Enemy();
       ~Enemy();

        enum Direction { UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT } direction;

        SDL_Rect position;  
        bool alive;

        int setAttributes(int x, int y, int w, int h);
        void update();
        bool checkCollision();
};
```

Then I want to create a vector for the enemies in the game...

```
vector<Enemy> enemy;
```

Then I try to call the class functions like this...

```
enemy->setAttributes(0, 50, 32, 32);
enemy->update();
```

But when I compile, I get the following errors...

```
~/code/cpp/sdl$ g++ -o name main.cpp game.cpp player.cpp bullet.cpp enemy.cpp level.cpp -lSDL -lSDL_image -lSDL_ttf -lSDL_mixer
level.cpp: In constructor ‘Level::Level()’:
level.cpp:14: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::vector<Enemy, std::allocator<Enemy> >’
level.cpp: In member function ‘void Level::update()’:
level.cpp:28: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::vector<Enemy, std::allocator<Enemy> >’
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector is not a pointer (and does not act like one), and hence does not have an `operator->` defined.  Using a vector of `Enemy`s is just like using an array of them with the subscript operator:

```
std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
enemies.push_back(Enemy());
enemies[0].update();
```

The reason you can use `operator->` on arrays is that arrays convert to pointers, and thus

```
Enemy enemies[5];
enemies->update();
```

is equivalent to

```
Enemy enemies[5];
(*enemies).update();
```

which is in turn equivalent to

```
Enemy enemies[5];
enemies[0].update();
```

However, just because this is possible does not mean it is a good idea: people will have much less trouble understanding your code if you write `enemies[0].update()` instead of `enemies->update()`.

If you want to go through a `vector<Enemy>` as you could with a pointer to an array, you should do

```
for (std::vector<Enemy>::iterator it = enemies.begin(); it < enemies.end(); ++it) {
    it->update();
}
```

If you're using C++11 and are lazy, you can write `auto` instead of `std::vector<Enemy>::iterator` and the compiler will figure out the type for you.  (You may also want to store the value of `enemies.end()` outside the loop so that you don't call the function each iteration, but this may be optimised out anyway).

Comment: `(*enemies).update();` or `enemies->update();` is not equal to `enemies[0].update();`

Comment: What is the difference, then?

Comment: Alright...Your answer helped me out, I just needed to make some modifications to what you gave me, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
enemy->setAttributes(0, 50, 32, 32);
enemy->update();
```

needs to be

```
enemy[0].setAttributes(0, 50, 32, 32);  // Assuming you have at least one object stored in the vector
enemy[0].update();
```

Note that the vector elements is not pointer to a object but the object itself.

Comment: I get a segmentation fault when I run it now...What do I need to do to store the objects in the vectors?  Another thing I was wondering is if I'd have any need to use the new and delete operators with vectors, or do the vectors already handle that?

Comment: You get segmentation fault because the vector is empty and you are invoking calls on a empty vector. As long as vector contents are objects and not pointer to objects, you don't have to worry about vector elements destructors. Destruction of individual object happens when vector falls out of scope.

Comment: I recommend you to go through a basic STL tutorial.

Comment: I understand that I'm getting the segmentation fault because the vector is empty...I just don't understand why it's empty when I've added to it using enemy.push_back(Enemy()); before invoking the calls.

Comment: If I comment out enemy[0].update();, it runs...So that's where the problem is.

Comment: Okay, now it works flawlessly...I changed the declaration to vector<Enemy *> enemy;, then used enemy.push_back(new Enemy());, and used enemy[0]->setAttributes(0, 50, 32, 32); and enemy[0]->update();.